# s there a way to get the timestamp for when a record was inserted or updated in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is the only way to explicitly add a column with default value current_timestamp()? or can we use snowflake change data capture feature: streams, changes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does not have triggers, which is how update times are done in PostgreSQL for example. And it does not have built update times, so explicit is your only option, but luckily it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

In snowflake you can have columns with default values

```
CREATE or replace table tempdw.sample_insert_time
(
  name varchar,
  insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
);

insert into tempdw.sample_insert_time (name)values('john_doe');

select * from tempdw.sample_insert_time;

NAME    INSERT_TIME
john_doe    2020-07-14 21:23:22.392
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering if I didn't have to do this and Snowflake had a way of storing insert times internally that I could retrieve

Comment: If this answers your question can you kindly choose it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: if you are talking about information_schema then yes you can query those tables to find more details about DML timings,COPY command history etc. Please check the documentation for the same.

Comment: I too thought of same solution but then saw snowflake documentation which says that this will not work if you use kafka streaming connector to insert data into snowflake. Regular JDBC/SQL inserts will take this default value.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake doesn't have triggers, but you can emulate their behaviour using streams and tasks, and I have a feeling that's what you're looking for:

https://visualbi.com/blogs/snowflake/change-data-capture-cdc-using-streams-tasks-snowflake/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I took a look and didn't see any timestamp column in there